# get a photo preview over v-for loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I want to have a photo preview in my code below. I'm working with BootstrapVue.

But I don't know where the problem is.. after looking in my Vue devtools I can see that the form-file has the picture, but my "watch" is not working..

It would be very helpful if someone can help me out !

My template:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="item in files" :key="item.id">
      <b-button v-b-toggle="item.id" variant="danger btn-block mb-2">
        Upload {{ item.id }}</b-button>
      <b-collapse :id="item.id" class="mt-2">
        <div class="m-2 mt-3">
          <table class="table table-striped mt-2">
            <tbody>
              <div class="mt-3 mb-2 ml-1">Upload</div>
              <b-form-file
                :v-model="item.request"
                placeholder="Upload ..."
                class="mb-2"
              ></b-form-file>
              <b-img
                v-if="item.request"
                :src="item.src"
                class="mb-3"
                fluid
                block
                rounded
              ></b-img>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </b-collapse>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

My script:

```
<script>
const base64Encode = (data) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(data);
    reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
    reader.onerror = (error) => reject(error);
  });

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      files: [
        { id: "1", src: null, request: null },
        { id: "2", src: null, request: null },
        { id: "3", src: null, request: null },
      ],
    };
  },

  watch: {
    files: {
      deep: true, //watch changes at objects properties
      handler(newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue !== oldValue) {
          if (newValue) {
            base64Encode(newValue.src)
              .then((value) => {
                newValue.src = value;
              })
              .catch(() => {
                newValue.src = null;
              });
          } else {
            newValue.src = null;
          }
        }
      },
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Is there errors in you console? ， you are watching files, but you change the newValue.src, then it trigger the watch again, Is it a loop call?

Comment: No errors in my console. My code is exactly the same ! - But when I comment out my watch function it's the same like having it in my code..

Comment: Normally you should be able to copy the code and run it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a little mistake!

Instead of writing `:v-model` for `b-form-file` component use `v-model`.

In watch property you cannot understand which upload inputs changed. So try using `input` event handler for `b-form-file`. Then you can pass index of each `files` and run `base64Encode` function.

You can see working version of your code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-night-3huzn).